# Unable to import .p12 certificate to cacerts

Tags: java, authentication, keytool, pkcs#12, jks

While importing `.p12` to `cacerts` I'm facing the following issue. First line says alias already exists and then when I try to overwrite it says alias not found. Please help me tackle this issue.

```
/usr/java/default/jre/bin/keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeystore     /usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/cacerts -srckeystore /home/sogadm/MB_copy/MB_client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass 123456 -alias mb_ca
Existing entry alias mb_ca exists, overwrite? [no]:  yes
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <mb_ca> does not exist
```

Comment: Do you have any private keys in .p12 file? And what JRE version you're using?

Answer (score 13):

It probably means that:

1. in `cacerts` you ***already have*** an entry with alias **mb_ca**
2. in `.p12` you **don't** have an entry with alias **mb_ca**

Try to do the following:

1. Use `-list` to see the existing entries of `.p12` and their alias. Adapted to your example it will be something like this: 
   `keytool -list -keystore /home/sogadm/MB_copy/MB_client.p12 -storepass 123456 -storetype PKCS12 -v`
2. `-delete` the existing **mb_ca** entry in `cacerts`, if it is a wrong one or if you don't need it
3. Use `-srcalias` and `-destalias` for better control

Actually, if `cacerts` is a trusted certificates store you shouldn't import to it the *private key* entry from your `.p12`. Export the *public key* first, then import it to `cacerts`:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore /home/sogadm/MB_copy/MB_client.p12 -storepass 123456 -storetype PKCS12 -alias p12_entry_alias -file /home/sogadm/MB_copy/MB_client.cer

keytool -importcert -keystore /usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -alias mb_client -file /home/sogadm/MB_copy/MB_client.cer
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unable to list the aliases in the .p12 file. Please help me with the command for it

Comment: This should work `keytool -list -keystore your_p12_file.p12 -storepass p12_password -storetype PKCS12 -v`

Comment: By the way, you are trying to import a `.p12` to `cacerts`. `p.12` are keystores with one private key entry. `cacerts` is a usual name for a trusted certificates store. Normally, you should not mix these two kinds of entries. To import the public key of your `p.12` entry, export it first and then import to `cacerts`. I'll add the commands to the answer.